# Display Icon on Specific Div When Hover on Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

Visit the [Icomooon.io](https://icomoon.io/) and check the function of display icon when we hover on menu `ul` and an icon appears on another `div`. Kindly send me the fiddle with their "hover to display an icon on another side" function. [image: See the Image for consideration]

Comment: I just need its javascript or jQuery function.

Comment: Have a look to jQuery `hover()` [Doc](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: But bro from the hover() the user will have been confused to change icon every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an small example:

```js
$('ul li').hover(function() {
  // mouse enter
  var logo = $(this).attr("data-icon"); // get logo from data-icon parameter
  $('.icon img').attr("src", logo); // change logo
}, function() {
  // mouse left
  $('.icon img').attr("src", "http://placehold.it/50x50"); // remove logo
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
</div>
<ul>
  <li data-icon="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/"><a href="#">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li data-icon="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/"><a href="#">Item 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This jQuery snippet changes the icon of the `img` element of the `div` with the `icon` class. It get's the logo from the `data-icon` parameter of the single `li` elements. If you enter the `li` element with the mouse (hover), it will change the icon. If you leave the mouse, it will go back.

Please notice: In this example are just placeholder images. You can use fixed images for that to get it working as expected.

Comment: Thanks Bro for your help.

Comment: If this works for you, you may consider to accept the answer and/or upvote it. If not, you can add more comments asking for a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

have you ever examine jquery hoverIntent plugin ?
http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: Not yet, but this plugin will create difficulty for the user to change icon classes every time.

Answer (score 0):

Working example of on hover changing images

> Javascript

```
    $('#one').hover(function(){
    $('#iconHolder').empty().prepend('<img id="theImg" width="20" height="20" src="http://image005.flaticon.com/1/svg/109/109255.svg" />')
});
$('#two').hover(function(){
    $('#iconHolder').empty().prepend('<img id="theImg" width="20" height="20" src="http://image005.flaticon.com/1/svg/109/109099.svg" />')
});
$('#three').hover(function(){
    $('#iconHolder').empty().prepend('<img id="theImg" width="20" height="20" src="http://image005.flaticon.com/1/svg/109/109066.svg" />')
});
```

> HTML

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="iconHolder"></div>
<button id="one">one</button><button id="two">two</button><button id="three">three</button>
```